# Javascript connecting to joomla msql db

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, http, joomla

I received a job where I need to make a website in joomla with a mysql db. I need to create a function using javascript that connects to the mysql db.
 any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side language, while databases run on your server. Therefore, Javascript can't directly connect to the database on it's own. You will need to mix PHP and Javascript to connect to the database, for example creating an API with PHP and using that API in your Javascript.

In-short: Javascript is a client-side language, databases are server-side.

Comment: first, thank you for your answer 
from what i read, i could also use ajax to connect to the database. my problem is that i still have no access to the current project. they just asked me to made one functionality and because of that im a bit confused still

Comment: In that case, maybe [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) link can give you some more information, but with pure javascript only you can't connect to a database, you will always need some kind of server-sided language.

Comment: but is it possible to make something like this with javascript and ajax? or do i need to use php?

Comment: You will need some kind of server-sided language. AJAX can make the link to that language and pass parameters, but AJAX on itself can't connect to a database, it will need, for example, a PHP file.